# Confusion with by-reference and by-value argument passing

Tags: c#

When I read internet sources, it is said that a user-defined class object is passed by reference. I got stuck at understanding the below codes' outputs:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public TestClass(int xx, int yy)
    {
        this.x = xx;
        this.y = yy;
    }
}

void tfn(TestClass a)
{
    a = new TestClass(3, 4);
}

tfn(c);
Console.WriteLine($"c.x: {c.x}.");
```

Running the above give: **c.x: 1.**

But I don't understand then why the below gives: **c.x: 3.**

```
void tfn(TestClass a)
{
    TestClass b = a;
    b.x = 3;
}

tfn(c);
Console.WriteLine($"c.x: {c.x}");
```

Why does it behave as above?

Comment: "user-defined class object is passed by reference" - no, *a reference* is passed, but that reference is passed by value.

Comment: Yes. So I get that s why the first output above (c.x: 1.) was so.  But I didnt understand why the second output was so.

Comment: In the second case, there is only one object, and all the references (though they are separate copies) refer to that same object.

Comment: ah nevermind, i guess the second block didnt really change the location that b points to...i guess?

Comment: I recommend you read this https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/references.html

Comment: Not sure if intended but `c` is undefined in both examples so that both do not make much sense.

Comment: `Testclass b = a;` does not create a new instance of Testclass. It's just creates a new reference to the same instance of Testclass. `a` and `b` refer to the same object, through different variables.
It's like your friend Bob that your mother calls Robby. Two names, same entity.

Answer (score 0):

> When I read internet sources, it is said that a user-defined class object is passed by reference.

There is a subtle distinction that either you or your internet sources (or both) are getting wrong.

In .NET, parameters are always passed by value by default. For reference types (like custom classes), however, that value *is* a reference. So when you do:

```
void tfn(TestClass a)
{
    a = new TestClass(3, 4);
}

tfn(c);
```

You are passing to `tfn` the value of a reference to `c`. The function then changes the value *within the function* to a *new* object, but the calling code still has a reference to the old object. It's only when you used `ref TestClass a` that the change in the value of `a` is reflected in the calling code.

As an analogy - suppose you had box labelled `A` and wanted someone to do something (a function) with that box. You can do that one of two ways. You can tell the person "do something with box A" (passing a reference by value) or tell the person "do something with the box identified on this piece of paper" and hand them a piece of paper with the value "A" on it.

In the fist method, if they instead get a *new* box and label it 'B', *that has no bearing on the original box*. You still can see the original box `A` and have no idea that another box that they called `A` even exists.

In the second method (pass by reference) if the person gets a new box, labels it `B`, writes "B" on the paper, and hands it back to you, you now have a "reference" to box B. Your reference has been changed.